# fill the empty box with correct word

Tags: vocabulary

I am preparing for TOEFL PPT test. I have this practice on my book

**Stone Age Thuggery**

> if you think modern society is violent, be grateful you didn't live in Neolithic Britain. A study of 350 ancient skulls has revealed that in the Stone Age, Britons h-- a o-- in 20 cha-- of be-- bashed ov-- the he-- at so-- point i--- their li---.

#### The question is to fill the spaces

I solved it like this:

> if you think modern society is violent, be grateful you didn't live in Neolithic Britain. A study of 350 ancient skulls has revealed that in the Stone Age, Britons h**as** a o**ne** in 20 cha**--** of be**ing** bashed ov**er** the he**ad** at so**me** point i**n** their li**ves**.

I just don't know what should i put in cha**--**? is it chanes please?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP's exam questions, which he seems to have made no effort to answer himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "Britons **had** a one in 20 **chance**"

The text is about Britons in the Stone Age - so they **had**, not **has**.

**x in x chance:** this means how likely something is. A one in 20 chance means that, statistically, one person out of 20 people would have their head bashed in. It can be represented as 1/20, or as a ratio of people who would and people who wouldn't have their head bashed in: 1:20.

One meaning of "chance" is "the possibility of a particular outcome in an uncertain situation; also :  the degree of likelihood of such an outcome " (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chance).

Comment: also pleas i have this filled, `the researchers have found that most of the tra-- were caused by bl-- instruments` can you please fill the spaces ?

Comment: See my comment in other answer.

Comment: would you check my new answer please http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15585/vocabulary-about-flexible-working

Answer (score 2):

It should be,

> *Britions **had a one in 20 chance** of being bashed over the head at some point in their lives.*

Comment: pleas just one thing, why chance, and not chance **s** ?

Comment: also pleas i have this filled, `the researchers have found that most of the tra-- were caused by bl-- instruments` can you please fill the spaces ?

Comment: It's idiomatic to say ***a** X in Y chance*. It's a chance. Please note that the question already gives the hint about the use of "a".

Comment: And it should be **had** indeed. I didn't read that it's about the Stone Age.

Comment: "a [one in 20] chance" - it is "a chance", not "chances". The second set: I think "traumas" for the first; definitely "blunt" for the second. Does the exercise give you any hints?

Comment: no no hints, that sentence was a compete for the sentence in my question. actually i just bought the book , i didn't bought the answer sheets

Comment: @Damkerng T. - Pretty grim if it's the present day! :)

Comment: @nxx Indeed! :-)

Comment: would you check my new answer please http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15585/vocabulary-about-flexible-working

Answer (score 1):

I don't no correct answer but I tried this 
Britions had a one in chance/change of being bashed over the head at some point in their lives

Comment: also pleas i have this filled, `the researchers have found that most of the tra-- were caused by bl-- instruments` can you please fill the spaces ?

Comment: trail/trace ..... blow